# How old was the Pripyat hospital МСЧ-126 at the time of Chernobyl disaster?

Tags: soviet-union, historical-accuracy, ukraine

After seeing praises (both in general and about the historically accurate display of Soviet Union) on the Chernobyl series, I decided to watch it.

In the first episode we see a hospital. What striked me as probably inaccurate is the condition of the hospital. Look at the window and the window sill - it looks like it's been there for a generation. But it doesn't seem that plausible as the city itself was very new back then.

[image: screenshot of the Chernobyl TV series showing unkept window of the hospital]

How old was the hospital at the time?

As far as I can find, the hospital is called MSCh-126 (МСЧ-126, Medical-Sanitary Unit No 126). I can't find the construction dates, but some images from recent years seem to show that the window sills couldn't be in such bad condition 30 years ago.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page on [Pripyat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pripyat), the town was founded on 4 February 1970, and proclaimed a city in 1979.  That would mean that the hospital could have been no more than 16 years old in 1986.

Comment: Do you mean to convey that you think perhaps either the real hospital may be older than the city, or that the producers were going for 'typical Soviet feel', post-meltdown aesthetics, or plain inaccuracy? AS you and sempa noticed, older than 16 years seems very unlikely for the real thing.

Comment: @LangLangC Yeah, I suspect they went with the "Soviet feel" and did it too much...

Comment: The windows don't appear to be as old even in 2014 https://www.bcd-urbex.com/pripyat-hospital-msch-126-medico-sanitary-unit/

Comment: Yep. But I guess, the exact date for the building might be an XY-Problem here. The goal seems to be a bit more to judge the accuracy of the chosen set. May I suggest to perhaps re-phrase the Q accordingly? (Unsure how though, myself. This goes quite deep for a minute detail?) But: the real age of the real thing seems secondary motivation/background to that?

Comment: @LangLangC I feel like the age of the building is indeed the exact detail that I want to become sure about. And I believe that someone who is good with Russian/Ukrainian sources could indeed provide an answer to that.

Comment: They probably filmed it in a real building from the same time period as MSCH-126 and which has natural age of 40+ year now. All details like window frame, locks,  size and proportions, window sill height, thickness and depth look very authentic for me and similar to these used in the real MSCH-126.